# Adding supported ciphers to ubuntu

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am trying to add two additional ciphers to a server ubuntu installation... How should I go about adding the additional ciphers?

Background: I am trying to add some old cipher support (for testing purposes):

- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

and have checked that they are not inside the `openssl ciphers` list

From the output of the command 'openssl ciphers -V', i only saw these 3 entries starting with TLS:

```
      0x13,0x02 - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
      0x13,0x03 - TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
      0x13,0x01 - TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

Comment: Betcha at least the latter is; try spelling `openssl ciphers RC4-SHA:AES256-SHA`. OpenSSL uses different names than the RFCs/IANA; add `-V` (uppercase) to get the code number(s) if you want to check. In 1.1.0 up all RC4 ciphers are included in the 'weak-ssl-ciphers' category which is unbuilt by default in upstream, but I don't know if Ubuntu changes that.

Comment: Anyone knows how to add the additional ciphers in?